# Issue with POST requests with Laravel Sanctum and Postman

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-sanctum

I have a problem with Sanctum and Postman that's related to this post: [SPA Authentication Issues with Sanctum and Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480576/spa-authentication-issues-with-sanctum-and-postman/67878595#67878595)

I followed everything from the Laravel docs about Sanctum and configured it correctly. Then I followed this tutorial: https://blog.codecourse.com/laravel-sanctum-airlock-with-postman/

Everything is working except for POST requests. When I do login, it works. But then I have a collection without the pre-request Script and when I do a GET request to for example `/user`, it will return the logged in user.

But when I change the method to `POST` in Laravel and in Postman, I'll get a CSRF token mismatch error.

Does anybody knows what I have to do, to make POST requests working?

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

[image: POST Request for /user]

Comment: i am getting the same issue, did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `sanctum` in one of my e-commerce APIs and I've also followed the same tutorial you've linked in the question. It's hard to tell what's the actual problem in your case but it seems like that you're not sending the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header in your `POST` requests.

The [last paragraph](https://blog.codecourse.com/laravel-sanctum-airlock-with-postman/#a-quick-note-on-other-web-routes) in the above-mentioned tutorial, the writer shows how to hit the `/logout` route which is a `POST` route.

Comment: That's correct, when I use the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` in the header along with a `POST` request, than it is working. But that is the same token over and over again.
I thought it was send automatically within de cookie?

Comment: Also de `/logout` is a call to the `/routes/web.php`, there you need a CSRF token. But I'm doing a request to the `/routes/api.php`.

Comment: can you please tell me how you send your `X-XSRF-TOKEN` with every `POST` request? Do you make a new one every request or use the same token over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this function in the controller

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Or change it to

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:sanctum');
}
```

Also, check your `RouteServiceProvider` and change your API route to

```php
Route::prefix('api/v1')
    ->middleware('auth:sanctum')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if you have not any collection in postman, create new one and put your request in the collection.
2. edit ***Tests*** tab in collection, put below code in the area

```
    var xsrfCookie = pm.cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN");
    pm.environment.set('xsrf-token', xsrfCookie);
```

[image]

3. add a new header to my request, with the following data

```
    Key: X-XSRF-TOKEN,
    Value: {{xsrf-token}}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

csrf_token is used to validate forms having method **POST** in laravel and token is created dynamically,
two thing you can do

First thing if you are writing api's you need to use `https://<base_url>/api`
and routes in **routes/api.php**, there you donot need **csrf_token** but make sure to use proper api authentication

Second just disable csrf token for those routes until you are testing on postman, once you successfully tested enable again, its provide security

disable like this

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
  protected $except = [
    'submitMyForm/*',
  ];
}
```

Comment: I am using the `routes/api.php` for the mentioned `/user` call. So it is not in the `routes/web.php`. I also changed the route so I can use a subdomain.
But I don't think it is good practice to disable the token. I don't understand WHY I get the CSRF token mismatch, because I'm doing a request to `/routes/api.php` where CSRF tokens aren't used right?